# Select tr and its "tr childs" - find jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My table looks like the following:

```
<table class="highlight">
 <tbody>
    <tr class="sortable"><td>first row</td></tr>
    <tr class="sortable nondraggable sub"><td>collasped row with further informations (belongs to row one)</td></tr>
    <tr class="sortable nondraggable sub"><td>collasped row with further informations (belongs to row one)</td></tr>
    <tr class="sortable nondraggable sub"><td>collasped row with further informations (belongs to row one)</td></tr>
    <tr class="sortable"><td>second row</td></tr>
    <tr class="sortable"><td>third row</td></tr>
    <tr class="sortable nondraggable sub"><td>collasped row with further informations (belongs to third row)</td></tr>
    <tr class="sortable"><td>fourth row</td></tr>
    <tr class="sortable"><td>fifth row</td></tr>
    <tr class="sortable nondraggable sub"><td>collasped row with further informations (belongs to fifth row)</td></tr>
    <tr class="sortable nondraggable sub"><td>collasped row with further informations (belongs to fifth row)</td></tr>
 </tbody>
```

I want to select each row with its "collapsed" childs.

For clarification: https://jsfiddle.net/4k1a6xp6/4/

I think it can be solved by using the child `">"` selector of jquery. 
So we can use `jQuery("table.highlight").find("tr.sortable > ??? ")`.

The ??? should select the child trs with "`sortable nondraggable sub`" until the next parent row is reached.

How can I accomplish this?

**[EDIT]** One possible solution based from answers: https://jsfiddle.net/4k1a6xp6/6/

Comment: And how do you know they are "collapsed" ?

Comment: `$('tr.sub')`.....

Comment: @adeneo this is done by angularjs. I think its here irrelevant - because it adds the proper css style regarding the state.

Comment: @PranavCBalan this tr.sub select only its childs.

Comment: @Briefkasten `$('tr.sub,tr.sub>td')`

Comment: *"should select the child trs with "sortable nondraggable sub" until the next parent row"* what do you mean *child* `<tr>`? did you mean to say `<td>` or do you mean child of `<table>`?

Comment: @TJ With child I mean the "collapsed" trs. For example: `<tr class="sortable"><td>first row</td></tr>` is a parent. `<tr class="sortable nondraggable sub"><td>collasped row with further informations (belongs to row one)</td></tr>
    ` is the child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the parent row (with a specific selector as shown below, or while iterating over each of them, as per your requirement) then use [nextUntil](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) with [:not](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector. For example:

```
$('tr.sortable').first().nextUntil('tr.sortable:not(.nondraggable.sub)')
```

Comment: Thanks, I used your code to achieve the following: https://jsfiddle.net/4k1a6xp6/6/ , is it possible to move this into a jquery selector query?

Comment: Thanks, I'm using jquery sortable and I have to determine how one item gets selected with jquery selector (tr parent + tr childs - like your above code does). The [sortable.items](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-items) option expects an selector. How can I assign `$('tr.sortable').first().nextUntil('tr.sortable:not(.nondraggable.sub)')` to JQueryUI.SortableOptions.items?

Comment: @Briefkasten I doubt you can create such a selector. Ideally jQuery UI should accept DOM elements, jQuery object, function etc as well. Since it doesn't, you'd be better of grouping your `tr` in `<tbody>`s. `<table>` can have multiple `<tbody>` in it. If you have an interactive UI it'd be better for you to throw away the table itself an create `<div>` structure instead...

Answer (score 0):

OK, as i understand you want to select both the Parent row and the collapsed rows.

Check out this fiddle below.

```
 $('tr.sub').css('background-color', 'yellow');

var sibling = $('tr.sub').prev();
//console.log(sibling);


$(sibling).each(function(index, item) {
  console.log(item);
  if (!$(item).hasClass('sub')) {
    $(item).css('background-color', 'blue');
  }

});
```

It assumes that your 'parent' row does not have any class and the check is made on the parent row's **absence** of the .sub class.

Colors are different just for highlighting purposes. If you could just add a class to the parent row, this will be more easier :)

Code snippet

```js
$('tr.sub').css('background-color', 'yellow');

var sibling = $('tr.sub').prev();
//console.log(sibling);
var solorows  = $('tr.sortable').next('.sortable:not(.nondraggable.sub)');

$(solorows).each(function(index,item){
//console.log(item);

if($(item).next('tr.nondraggable.sub')){
 $(item).css('background-color','red')
}
});

$(sibling).each(function(index, item) {
 // console.log(item);
  if (!$(item).hasClass('sub')) {
    $(item).css('background-color', 'yellow');
  }

});
```

```css
.highlight {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="highlight">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="sortable">
      <td>first row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sortable nondraggable sub">
      <td>collasped row with further informations (belongs to row one)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sortable nondraggable sub">
      <td>collasped row with further informations (belongs to row one)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sortable nondraggable sub">
      <td>collasped row with further informations (belongs to row one)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sortable">
      <td>second row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sortable">
      <td>third row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sortable nondraggable sub">
      <td>collasped row with further informations (belongs to third row)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sortable">
      <td>fourth row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sortable">
      <td>fifth row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sortable nondraggable sub">
      <td>collasped row with further informations (belongs to fifth row)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sortable nondraggable sub">
      <td>collasped row with further informations (belongs to fifth row)</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: That looks good, but second row and fourth row should be selected too. like in this example: https://jsfiddle.net/4k1a6xp6/4/

Comment: @Briefkasten well , i didnt catch that in the question earlier. :) Anyway just updated the fiddle , if it does any good !